# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory but directory was created and shows in Finder

Tags: python

I am doing a batch upload with Python 2.7 from a Mac and my command line parameters look like this: --list ./up.csv --dest ./media --results ./res.csv . 
Whether I include the slash or not in front of my destination folder, the result is the same, i.e. after running the script, the media folder will appear in my directory, but I will get the error: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './media/nameOfFile. (The media in question is a list of urls listed in the up.csv)

The error message references this line in the code:

```
with open(os.path.join(dest_path, filename), 'w') as ofile:
```

Why does it create the file, but at the same time throw this error, and how can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: just making sure, but is there a `:` at the end of your `with open` line in your actual code?

Comment: yes thanks @ryugie just edited it to show that